# Is the number of finite strings infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I already asked this question on Stack Overflow and people kept voting me down and telling me it's "more of a maths question" so I will ask the question again:

Assuming a finite alphabet, (eg: A,B), can we construct an infinite set of finite strings? Obviously we'll start with the empty string, then A, then B, then AB, AA BA, BB... etc

I made the claim (with much disagreement and voting-down) that it's impossible to have an infinite set of finite strings, because if we take out alphabet as 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, and make our strings have a 1-to-1 correspondence with the natural numbers starting with 0, (so each string is a natural number), then there must be a maximum-length of a string in this set (a finite number, we'll call it N). If this is so, we may take the highest number in the set of length N (which will also be the highest natural number) and count down to 0, removing each number from the set, until we have the empty set. On the other hand if N=Infinity then the set contains infinite strings.

I've been met with much disdain for saying this, intuitively I find impossible to believe that there's such thing as an infinite set of finite strings.

Comment: Note that the natural numbers have the property that each number has a greater number (successor) wich is also a natural number. Thus, there is no greatest natural number.

Comment: "On the other hand if N=Infinity then the set contains infinite strings." No, if $N=\infty$ (as in Sal's example) then that only implies that there are *arbitrarily long* strings, not necessarily strings of infinite length.

Answer (score 8):

Even simpler,$$\{A, \quad AA,\quad AAA,\quad AAAA,\quad\ldots\}$$
Compare this to the observation that $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$ is an infinite set of numbers, each of which is nevertheless finite. There is no reason that a set of numbers must have a maximum number, just like there is no reason that a set whose elements are finite length strings must have maximum length string.

Reading your question further, you seem to be under the impression that there is a largest natural number. I can't imagine what you might think it would be, much less what you think the result would be if you added one to it (*gasp!*).

Comment: To make this even more blunt: is the set of finite natural numbers infinite?

Comment: To your final comment, I recall a documentary about infinity (I think by the BBC) where they interviewed Doron Zeilberger, a renowned ultrafinitist, and he said that it is his belief that there is a largest natural number and when you add $1$ to it, you get $0$. Of course, he added, this number is larger than anything we can even begin to imagine (which is in some sense not different than infinity as most mathematicians would perceive it, in my opinion).

Answer (score 4):

Belief has nothing to do with it.

Either you accept the "classical" (and somewhat implicit) rules of mathematics, which permit an infinite set of finite strings. Or you reject them, in which case you have to tell us what you think is true or false.

Your argument completely fails, because there is no "maximal length finite string" of digits, since in that case there would only be finitely many natural numbers. Remember that mathematics is an ideal space, it is not bounded by memory or running time. Since every natural number has a successor, there are infinitely many of them, all of which have a finite decimal expansion that eventually gets longer and longer and longer... but still finite.

(Let me add that infinite sets, which are an integral part of modern mathematics, are far far stranger than you could begin to imagine. An infinite set of finite strings is merely the tip of the quark of the edge of the electron of the edge of the hydrogen atom of the water molecule of the tip of the iceberg. It gets much crazier as you proceed. But it's the good kind of crazy!)

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean. I'm not going to attempt to "argue with mathematics" I'm just giving my intuition on the subject along with an argument. I'm studying computer science not maths, and if you say there's no maximal length of a string in this set, then that's great. Personally I think I've provided an argument that leads to some kind of contradiction (or at least some doubt) but all these maths snobs are quick to silence me and I've better things to do. Oh well...

Comment: Just one more thing for you to ponder: N must be either finite or infinity. If it's not infinity => It's not an infinite set. If it is infinity, there are infinite strings. Can you directly disprove this argument without resorting to "countably infinite" and all that stuff? Maybe all that stuff is wrong, or maybe I'm wrong.. I feel like I'm wasting my time because everyone keeps resorting to this "arbitrarily long" argument which (to me) must include infinity. Otherwise it's range-bound. Still I know nobody will listen to me and they'll rattle off their "proofs"... Right. End of rant.

Comment: I don't understand your argument at all, so I can't quite refute it. $\Bbb N$ is the set of natural numbers, it is an infinite set. But its elements are *finite* integers. If you disagree that there are infinitely many finite integers, you won't accept that $\Bbb N$ is infinite; if you do accept it, then there's really nothing to argue. To see that $\Bbb N$ is infinite, note that if $A$ is a finite set, then every injection is also a surjection; but in the case of $\Bbb N$ the function $f(n)=n+1$ is injective but not surjective, as are $g(n)=2n$ and $h(n)=n^2$.

Comment: @nodger: It really doesn't mean anything to say that something "is" or "is not" `infinity` (not without a lot more discussion of which of the many meanings of the word `infinity` is being used). The opposite adjective of `finite`, the word that means "not finite", is `infinite`. Thus the correct version of what you said that "$\mathbb{N}$ is finite or infinite". As it happens, the set $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite.

Comment: @nodger: This is an important distinction, not only because it will help focus on what precisely your disagreement is on, but because there are in fact other infinite sets ($\mathbb{R}$, the real numbers, for example), and you would be additionally confused by saying "$\mathbb{N}$ is infinity" and $\mathbb{R}$ is infinity" since it would seem to follow somehow that $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{R}$, which is both intuitively and rigorously incorrect. However, it is no contradiction at all to have an adjective that applies to two different entities, such as "That car is red" and "That apple is red".

Comment: @Sal I'm obviously in over my head here. I haven't studied this stuff in great detail and am not aware of the fact that there are many infinities. I've exhausted my mathematical arsenal and would like to bow out. I thought my argument was sound (although simple), from what I've picked up, "arbitrarily long" means finite but with an unspecified length (of which there is no maximum)..erm. isn't that infinity? Ok, Job done.

Comment: @nodger: To say that a set `contains finite strings that are arbitrarily long` doesn't mean it contains `strings of unspecified length`. Indeed, that wouldn't really make sense - once you have a given, specified string in mind, you can find its length right then and there. The concept of `arbitrarily long` only applies to a *collection of strings*, and it means `for any finite length, there is at least one string in the collection that's at least that long`.

Comment: @nodger: It's really hard to explain these topics to someone that is not planning on opening up a book and reading about them. Because at some point it boils down to "You're just gonna have to trust me on this one". Sal is doing *a wonderful* job trying to explain this to you, but unless you're really interested to walk the extra mile and learn all that stuff properly (which is not hard, just requires some time and dedication), I really think that we need to part as friends. **Sal:** Thank you for the effort in those comments, I know that those are not easy to write!

Comment: @Sal I don't mean any disrespect, And I've come up with my own proof of how there are infinite finite strings. If you care to hear it, it is: 1. Take an infinite string (over an alphabet ABC) of the form ABCAAABACBABBBC... and so forth... basically the concatenation of all the 1-strings, the 2-strings, etc... then chop it up into the 1-strings, 2strings,etc... and hey presto, infinitely many finite strings. Right, I get it now

Comment: @nodger: Your proof is a bit circular. You began by taking the string which is the concatenation of all the $1$-strings, $2$-strings and so on. In order for this to be infinite, you need to already assume that there are infinitely many finite strings. However, your proof can be fixed to be a bit like Euclid's proof of the infinitude of the prime numbers. There are at least two strings $A$ and $AA$. Given a finite set of finite strings, their concatenation is longer than all the strings in the finite set, so it is different from them, therefore that set didn't include all the finite strings[...

Comment: ...] It follows, if so, that no finite set contains all the finite strings, and therefore there must be infinitely many of them.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Still, having said all that, I have a problem with this idea that an infinite set of finite things (strings) cannot have a maximum, even if it is undefined but known to be between 0 and infinity (but not infinity). Maths is supposed to be about working with all the information we have and drawing conclusions. What's stopping me from saying the length of the longest string in the set is N, which is a natural number below infinity and greater or equal to zero? Then since N is a finite number, thus finitely many strings. Please tell me why I'm not *Allowed* to use this reasoning?

Comment: @nodger: You are allowed to use this reasoning, but you will arrive to a contradiction. If $s$ is a string of length $N$, then the concatenation of $s$ with itself will be a string of length $N+N$, so either the sum of two natural numbers is not a natural number; or $N=0$ (meaning there are no strings at all); or there is a finite string longer than what you claimed to be the maximal length of a finite string.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument seems to revolve around the length of the members being finite. Note that in a set of finite strings, each string must have a *finite* length, but this length ($N$) need not be the same for all members. This means:

- Given a number $N$, the set $\Sigma^{\le N}$ of strings with length *at most $N$* is finite (you argue about such sets)
- The set $\Sigma^\ast$ of strings of finite length ($\Sigma^\ast = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} \Sigma^{\le n}$) is *infinite* because to any string with "maximal length" you could append a member of $\Sigma$ to obtain a longer element of $\Sigma^\ast$, so since there are strings of arbitrary length in $\Sigma^\ast$ and since $\mathbb N$ is inifinite, so is $\Sigma^\ast$
- In fact you gave a sketch proof that $\Sigma^\ast$ is *countably infinite* for any finite alphabet $\Sigma$ by (a) seeing that $\Sigma^\ast$ is infinite and (b) giving an enumeration of $\Sigma^\ast$, i.e. a systematic way to assign a natural number to any finite string in $\Sigma^\ast$.